# Haskell print string without newline

Tags: haskell, printing, newline

When I use this code it's print newline after result. How I can don't write newline?

```
import System.IO

main :: IO ()
main  = do
        a <- getLine
        b <- getLine
        let aa = read a :: Int
        let bb = read b :: Int
        let cc = aa + bb
        print cc
```

Answer (score 22):

`print` is [defined as `putStrLn . show`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/System-IO.html#print), the fix is to use `putStr . show $ cc`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also `putStr` instead of `putStrLn.` Not sure how you would do something similar with `print` though.